# signed integer is greater than maximum in scikit-learn in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis of around 30,000 tweets. python version is 2.7 on linux. In the training phase I am using `nltk` as a wrapper for `sklearn` library to apply different Classifiers such as Naive Bayes, LinearSVC, Logistic regression , etc.

It works fine when the number of tweets are like 10,000 but now I received error for 30,000 tweets on classifying Bigrams with Multinomial naive bayes in `sklearn`. Here is part of the implementation code after pre-processing and dividing to train and test sets :

```
import nltk
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,

training_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extractFeatures, trainTweets)
testing_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extractFeatures, testTweets)

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
MNBAccuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set)*100
print "-------- MultinomialNB --------"
print "RESULT : Matches  " + str(int((testSize*MNBAccuracy)/100)) + ":"+ str(testSize)
print "MNB accuracy percentage:" + str(MNBAccuracy)
print ""
```

here the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sb402747/Desktop/Sentiment/sentiment140API/analysing/Classifier.py", line 83, in <module>
    MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
    X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 226, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 176, in _transform
    indptr.append(len(indices))
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

I guess the reason is because the number of indices in array is more that the maximum allowed for it on `dict_vectore.py`. I even tried to change the type of indices in `dict_vectorizer.py` from `i` to `l` but it didn't solve my problem and received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sb402747/Desktop/Sentiment/ServerBackup26-02-2016/analysing/Classifier.py", line 84, in <module>
    MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
    X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 226, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 186, in _transform
    shape=shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/rwthfs/rz/SW/UTIL.common/Python/2.7.9/x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.check_format(full_check=False)
  File "/rwthfs/rz/SW/UTIL.common/Python/2.7.9/x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 167, in check_format
    raise ValueError("indices and data should have the same size")
ValueError: indices and data should have the same size
```

then discarded it and changed it back to `i` again. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like here:

```
File "/home/sb402747/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 115, in train
X = self._vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
```

nltk demands too big matrix as a result.
Maybe you can change it somehow, for example minimize number of features (words) in your text, or request for this result in two passes?

Also, are you trying to do this on latest numpy/scipy/scikit-learn stable releases?

Read this too: https://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/31340515/